# A better way to aggregate into a default value

Tags: sql, oracle, join, group-by, query-optimization

For this example I have three tables (individual, business, and ind_to_business).  Individual has information on people.  Business has information on businesses.  And ind_to_business has information on which people are linked to which business.  Here are their DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE individual
(
 ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 NAME VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
 ENTERPRISE_ID VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
CREATE TABLE business
(
 ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 NAME VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
 ENTERPRISE_ID VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
CREATE TABLE ind_to_business
(
  ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  IND_ID REFERENCES individual(id),
  BUS_ID REFERENCES business(id),
  START_DT DATE NOT NULL,
  END_DT DATE
);
```

I'm looking for the best way to display one row for each person.  If they are linked to one business, I want to display the the business's `ENTERPRISE_ID`.  If they are linked to more than one business, I want to display the default value 'Multiple'. They will always be linked to a business, so there is no `LEFT JOIN` necessary.  They can also be linked to a business more than once (Leaving and coming back).  Multiple records for the same business would be aggregated.

So for the following sample data:

#### Individual:

```
+----+------------+---------------+
| ID |    NAME    | ENTERPRISE_ID |
+----+------------+---------------+
|  1 | John Smith | 53a23B7       |
|  2 | Jane Doe   | 63f2a35       |
+----+------------+---------------+
```

#### Business:

```
+----+----------+---------------+
| ID |   NAME   | ENTERPRISE_ID |
+----+----------+---------------+
|  3 | ABC Corp | 2a34d9b       |
|  4 | XYZ Inc  | 34bf21e       |
+----+----------+---------------+
```

#### ind_to_business

```
+----+--------+--------+-------------+-------------+
| ID | IND_ID | BUS_ID |  START_DT   |   END_DT    |
+----+--------+--------+-------------+-------------+
|  5 |      1 |      3 | 01-JAN-2000 | 31-DEC-2002 |
|  6 |      1 |      3 | 01-JAN-2015 |             |
|  7 |      2 |      3 | 01-JAN-2000 |             |
|  8 |      2 |      4 | 01-MAR-2006 | 05-JUN-2010 |
|  9 |      2 |      4 | 15-DEC-2019 |             |
+----+--------+--------+-------------+-------------+
```

I would expect the following output:

```
+---------+------------+------------+
| IND_ID  |    NAME    | LINKED_BUS |
+---------+------------+------------+
| 53a23B7 | John Smith | 2a34d9b    |
| 63f2a35 | Jane Doe   | Multiple   |
+---------+------------+------------+
```

Here is my current query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       sub.ind_id,
       sub.name,
       DECODE(sub.bus_count, 1, sub.bus_id, 'Multiple') AS LINKED_BUS
FROM (SELECT i.enterprise_id AS IND_ID, 
             i.name,
             b.enterprise_id AS BUS_ID,
             COUNT(DISTINCT b.enterprise_id) OVER (PARTITION BY i.id) AS BUS_COUNT
      FROM individual i
      INNER JOIN ind_to_business i2b ON i.id = i2b.ind_id
      INNER JOIN business b ON i2b.bus_id = b.id) sub;
```

My query works, but this is running on a large dataset and taking a long time to run.  I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas on how improve this so that there isn't so much wasted processing (i.e Needing to do a `DISTINCT` on the final result or doing `COUNT(DISTINCT)` in the inline view only to use that value in the `DECODE` above).

I've also created a DBFiddle for this question. ([Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=625f8991f0e5b14a540b3cdd2c84be50))

Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: No need to use DISTINCT twice, you could take the distinct data in the subquery itself and then aggregate the rows. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join with the aggregated `ind_to_business` per individual. One way to do this:

```
select i.id, i.name, coalesce(b.enterprise_id, 'Multiple')
from individual i
join
(
  select
    ind_id,
    case when min(bus_id) = max(bus_id) then min(bus_id) else null end as bus_id
  from ind_to_business
  group by ind_id
) ib on ib.ind_id = i.id
left join business b on b.id = ib.bus_id
order by i.id;
```

Comment: This pattern seems to work the best among the answers.  I did however make one change that seemed to improve performance.  Instead of a `CASE` statement, I used `DECODE`.  The increase was minimal, but when the query is going to be run many times, every little bit counts.

Comment: I'm glad the query works well for you. As to `CASE` versus `DECODE`: this is unlikely to make a measurable difference. It is more likely that the time difference you saw had other reasons (data already in the cache or the like). `CASE` is standard SQL and `DECODE` is not, but just use what you find more readable.

Answer (score 2):

You could try and use a correlated subquery. This removes the need for outer `distinct`:

```
SELECT 
    i.enterprise_id ind_id,
    i.name,
    (
        SELECT DECODE(COUNT(DISTINCT b.enterprise_id), 1, MIN(bus_id), 'Multiple')
        FROM ind_to_business i2b
        INNER JOIN business b ON i2b.bus_id = b.id
        WHERE i2b.ind_id = i.id
    ) linked_bus
FROM individual i
```

Comment: I think this has to be `MIN(bus_id)` or `MAX(bus_id)` in the `DECODE` expression.

Comment: @LalitKumarB: we have aggregate expressions in the select clause so that's implicit aggregation. Pretty much like when you do: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable`.

Comment: @GMB Ok, now you added `MIN`, it wasn't there when I commented :-) And yeah, I did the same thing in my query just that I did the DISTINCT in the subquery and aggregation on top. You have it correlated, another good way!

Comment: @GMB I usually don't like correlated subqueries, as I've seen them used too often by developers instead of understanding the data model.  But I think you may be on to something, I guess it is all about using the pattern correctly.

Answer (score 0):

No need of using `DISTINCT` twice. You could use `subquery factoring` and put the in-line view in `WITH` clause, and make the data set `DISTINCT` in the subquery itself.

```
WITH data AS
(
  SELECT distinct 
       i.enterprise_id AS IND_ID, 
       i.name,
       b.enterprise_id AS BUS_ID
  FROM individual i
  JOIN ind_to_business i2b ON i.id = i2b.ind_id
  JOIN business b ON i2b.bus_id = b.id
)
SELECT ind_id,
       name,
       case 
         when count(*) = 1 then MIN(bus_id)
         else 'Multiple' 
       end AS LINKED_BUS
FROM data
GROUP BY ind_id, name;

IND_ID     NAME       LINKED_BUS               
---------- ---------- -------------------------
53a23B7    John Smith 2a34d9b                  
63f2a35    Jane Doe   Multiple
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should sub-query to get all needed dimensions and then do all your final aggregation using `CASE` statement.

```
select
    ind_id,
    name,
    case
        when count(*) > 1 then 'Multiple'
        else ind_id
    end as linked_bus
from
(
    select 
        distinct i.enterprise_id as ind_id, 
        i.name,
        b.enterprise_id as bus_id
    from individual i

    join ind_to_business i2b 
    on i.id = i2b.ind_id

    join business b 
    on i2b.bus_id = b.id
) vals

group by
    ind_id,
    name
order by
    ind_id
```

Comment: That is not what the OP has asked for.